# Whats the difference between content and structure folders in AEM

Tags: aem, ecm, aem-6

I am using Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.3. In the basic structure, components folder contains content and structure folders.
In both the folders we put components. What is the difference in both the folders?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In simple terms, Components which are responsible for rendering the skeleton or the outermost part of the page are placed in the `structure` folder where as components which render only parts of the page are placed in `content` folder.
Note that this is just a best practice recommendation from Adobe, you can maintain folders with custom names as well.

In older versions of AEM, components in `structure` folder were placed in `page` folder and were called `page components`.

---

High-level flow of how `structure` and `content` components integrate in a page -

- To create a page in AEM, you'll have to select a template.
- A template is first created in `/conf` folder. Templates are usually backed up(`sling:resourceType` of the template points to `structure` component) by a `structure` component to render the initial view. Common `structure` components includes `header`, `footer`, `body` which usually contains container components like `parsys` or `responsivegrid`.
- A page is then created using the template created above and the content author uses functional components (components in `content`) to design the page - drag and drop from components side rail or sidekick in previous versions.